# MongoDB: Match operation with dayOfWeek filter

Tags: mongodb

I have the following object:

```
{
    ...
    "junctionId" : "6301",
    "ts" : ISODate("2016-08-10T11:17:47.000Z")
    ...
}
```

I want to filter the documents that which doesn't have timestamp of particular day of week.

I can this by:

```
db.getCollection('phasedata-test').aggregate([
{ $match : {
    ts : { $gte : ISODate('2016-08-18T21:00:00.000Z'), $lte: ISODate('2016-08-25T21:30:00.000Z') },
    junctionId : { $eq : "6301"}} 
},
{
    $sort: {ts : 1}
},

{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "year": { "$year": "$ts" },
        "month": { "$month": "$ts" },
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$ts" },
        "hour":  { "$hour": "$ts" },
        "interval": {
            "$subtract": [
                { "$minute": "$ts" },
                { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$ts"}, 15 ] }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dayOfWeek": { "$first": { "$dayOfWeek": "$ts" }},
    }
},

{ $match :{
    "dayOfWeek" : { $eq : 5}} 
}
```

Please don't look at `id grouping`. It is necessary for my query.

Number of documents can be big, so I want to reduce number of documents to be processed. How can I use **day of week** filter in **first match operation**?

With regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$addFields` aggregation as the first stage before matching:

```
[{
    $addFields: {
        DayOfWeek: {
            $dayOfWeek: {
                date: "$date"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        DayOfWeek: {
            $eq: 5
        }
    }
}, {}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful solution will be the easiest one: add field `dayOfWeek`your base document.

The create an index on it ... and everything works perfect :-)

=================

That was the easy way - but there be a cost - every time `ts` field will be updated, then `dayOfWeek` will have to be updated too.

Comment: Yeah, this solution would be elegant in some way but object model is already developed and code also written, so I don't want change so much :-).